# VB.NET Closing Workbook of Chartdata

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, powerpoint, excel-interop

I hope you are all safe and healthy!

**What i am trying to do:**
Using VB.NET I open a Powerpoint template and update the Charts located in said template.
Odly this worked fine, just until recently, but lets forgett about that for a second.

**Where is the problem?:**
The problem starts, where the task ends -> after i am finished updating, i can't seem to close the Workbook of the chartData.
I get the following Error-Message:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exceltion of HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

**My Code (simplyfied) looks something like this:** (Error appears at the bottom of code)

```
'Preparing the Variables
Dim j As Integer
Dim slide = pp.Slides(1)
Dim shape = slide.Shapes
slide = pp.Slides(5)
shape = slide.Shapes
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim chart As PowerPoint.Chart

'Prepare the Chart
chart = shape.Item("Diagramm 13").Chart
'Access the ChartData
chart.ChartData.Activate()
wb = CType(chart.ChartData.Workbook, Excel.Workbook)
ws = CType(wb.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
ws.UsedRange.ClearContents()

wb.Close()     '<--This is where it stops and throws a 
               '"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" Exception
wb = Nothing
```

**What i've already tried:**

- I tried closing it right after the  ChartData.Activate() line
- I tried closing it right after the  ChartData.Activate() line with "chart.ChartData.Workbook.Close" instead
- Activating the wb once more before closing it
- Checking if the Name of the wb somehow changed by writing the wb.name on a variable -> looks like its the correct name.

Have you any idea to whats wrong here?
Here is the 
If needed, i can provide further informations!

Thanks for your help and time,

best,
Alex

**UPDATE:**

I had created a release earlier today, because i wasn't expecting those problems. While i was then working on fixing them, a colleague of mine actually was able to run the release without an error.... I am totaly confused now. Can such a simple code actually stop working because of some random update on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly i wasn't able to try out the suggestion provided by Marco Hönsch.

I got my Office reinstalled and upgraded to Office 19 from Office 16.
And the Code instantly works again.
Sadly i am not able to provide an accurate anwser, since it could have either been an damaged office, that caused this error. Or the problem was related to the office version itself.

Either way, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (in C#).

Replacing...

```
wb.Close()
```

...with...

```
wb.Application.Quit()
```

...solved it in my case!